# Интегрировать API в WordPress для фильтра

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница на WP по съему квартир - Goodapart.com.ua. Есть сервис в интернете apartment24.com.ua на котором хранятся все записи об аренде.

Неободимо синхронизировать так, чтобы при поиске квартиры показывало какие из них свободны. Сейчас отображаются все что есть.

Связался с поддержкой этого сервиса, прислали 2 ссылки на API и это:
для фильтров гет параметры:
rooms_count=&price=&check_in=2020-10-24&check_out=2020-10-26&guests_count=1.

Подскажите как настроить фильтры, никогда раньше не сталкивался с подобной задачей

Answer (score 0):

По логике вещей, тебе нужно отправить `GET` запрос на API данного сервиса с указанными GET параметрами. Такого рода запросы, ты можешь отправлять как при помощи JS, получить ответ от сервиса и обаботать его так и при помощи PHP, предварительно написав аякс, который будет отправлять тебе на бекенд значения твоих выбранных фильтров (либо введенного поискового слова) и ты уже с бекенда будешь отправлять запрос, следственно на бекенде будешь обрабатывать ответ. Для отправки запросов ты можешь использовать как стандартную библиотеку `cURL`, но так как у тебя WordPress, я бы все же пользовался бы инструментами его [HTTP API](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6462/wordpress-http-api.html), тебе можно использовать ф-цию `wp_remote_get();`, почитать подробнее о ней можно [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_remote_get). Так же для дебага, да и в принципе в работе с сторонними API, я бы советовал использовать Postman, скачать можно [здесь](https://www.postman.com/)